# What can I say to express disgust or dislike?

Tags: interjections

Is there an interjection in Esperanto to express disgust or dislike?

In Swedish we have a whole bunch. For example "Blä" which is like *naŭze* and "Hua" which comes in several variations and is closer to *terure*. Then we have "usch" lying somewhere in between. "Ursch då" can mean something like *domaĝe*.

*Naŭze, terure* and *domaĝe* are fine, but I'm looking for an interjection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard one is ***Fi!***

It is linked to the prefix *fi-* expressing disapproval, and because this disapproval may be the result of disgust, *Fi!* can be extended to disgust. From Zamenhof's translation of *The Inspector General*:

> *Fi!* (Kraĉas.) *Eĉ naŭzas, tiel forte mi volas manĝi.*

Two comparable interjections in Zamenhof's writings are *Ba!* and *Pa!* (dismissal or annoyance)

You may sometimes encounter the interjection *Aĉ!* which is derived from *-aĉ-* (low quality) and expresses dissatisfaction or disappointment.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that interjection are mostly automatic reactions, and as such, I'm pretty sure one would simply use the ones one's used to in one's native language.
It seems to me that in most language they sound pretty similar, and the ugly face one would make at that moment should need no translation. Baaah or berk sound natural for me in French, and I wouldn't be hesitating using them in English. Esperanto being mainly a second language with conscious/voluntary speakers, I can't imagine any misunderstanding in that field of expression (at least for the most basic human reactions).