# Ekkrio pro malpureco aŭ naŭziĝo

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Kion vi ekkrius/dirus, kiam vi trovus subite kaj neatendante ion aparte malpuran, naŭzan, malbonodoran, ktp?

Mi ne povis trovi bonan esprimon por tio. Mi nur trovis en mia nederlanda-Esperanto-vortaro *pu!*, pri kio estas dirata ‘naŭzo de malbonodoro’. En [PMEG mi nur trovis *fi!*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/ekkrioj_sonimitoj/oficialaj_ekkrioj.html#i-k8h) por io ĝenerale abomena aŭ malbona; sed tio laŭ mi ne estas sufiĉe specifa.

Mi serĉas esprimon kiel la anglan *gross* aŭ la nederlandajn *gadver* kaj *gadverdamme*.
Mi krome scivolas, ĉu onomatopeo kiel *iŭ!* estus komprenebla. (Ekzemple, se vi legus tion en libro, ĉu vi tuj komprenus, ke temas pri naŭzaĵo/malpuraĵo?)

Comment: Jen la sama demando, sed en la angla https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/what-can-i-say-to-express-disgust-or-dislike

Answer (score 3):

Ankaŭ mi ne trovis pretan krivorton. Tial mi diras "ho naŭze!"

Comment: Tio ne estas malbona! Kion vi pensas pri la onomatopeo?

Comment: Gxi ne aparte placxas al mi kaj mi pensas ke gxi ne estas klara. Ebla la jena sercxo en Google (sen citloj) estus interesa por vi: "site:reta-vortaro.de ekkrio"

Comment: Hm, per tiu serĉo mi trovis neniun ekkrion, kiu povus taŭgi.

Comment: Jes ... sed multajn ekkriojn por aliaj uzoj. Nun ni povas esti iomete pli certaj ke ni ne maltrafis bonan respondon en RV.

Comment: Aha, jes, ĝuste.

Answer (score 2):

By analogy with fi, the suffix aĉ has been proposed as an interjection: [https://eo.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/aĉ](https://eo.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/a%C4%89)!

Comment: Similarly to _fi_, _aĉ_ would also be too generic.

Comment: Same http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/ listas `aĉ!`. @Joffysloffy though `naŭze` or a `vom*` certainly are more strong and negative, (en) oh no / (nl) gadver, jakkes / (de) iggit are similarly nondescript.

Comment: Interesting. It does not really matter that the exclamation be strong; preferably it be usable in most situations and not be completely vulgar. (Actually, the Dutch _gadver_ and _jakkes_ are specifically for disgusting things; so it is not like the English _oh no_.)